# Am I adding Spring Security to my project correctly? Access error after authorization

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

`Spring-MVC` project. There are 3 classes Cook, Cytomer andes Admin. All of them are inherited through *@OneToOne* from `User`. I added `Spring-Security` on tutorials and guides. But after authorization, no entity method is available to me. For example, if I log in as `Cook`, he does not call his `methods`, gives json an error:

```java
403 FORBIDDEN
```

I don’t know what to do. Looked at all the documentation. I checked the bugs, but I can’t figure out what I’m doing wrong.

WebSecConfig:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(jsr250Enabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    // Поля
    //
    private UserService userService;

    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;



    // Injects in SETTERS
    //
    @Autowired
    public void setUserService(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setPasswordEncoder(PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
    }



    // Methods
    //
    // Тут мы переопределяем метод конфигураций
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/home").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .permitAll();
    }


    // Тут мы переопределяем для работы с внешней БД
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    }


    // Beans
    //
    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userService);
        authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
        return authenticationProvider;
    }


    @Bean
    public static PasswordEncoder getPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(8);
    }

}
```

User

```java
@ApiModel
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "pg_user", schema = "public")
public class User implements UserDetails {

    // Roles
    //
    public static final String ROLE_ADMIN = "ADMIN";
    public static final String ROLE_CUSTOMER = "CUSTOMER";
    public static final String ROLE_COOK = "COOK";
    //


    public User() { // Пустой конструктор для Hibernate

    }


    // Поля
    private @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    Long id;

    @Column(name = "login")
    private String login;

    @Size(min = 5, max = 30)
    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "role")
    private String role;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;


    // Методы
    //
    // GrantedAuthority
    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return Collections.singletonList(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + role));
    }


    // userName == login (одно и тоже)
    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return login;
    }


    // Во всех флагах стоит TRUE, так как они не используются
    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }
    //
}
```

UserServ:

```java
@Service
public class UserService implements UserDetailsService {


    // Fields
    //
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;


    // Injects are here
    //
    @Autowired
    public void setUserRepository(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setPasswordEncoder(PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
    }


    // Методы
    //
    //
    public static User getCurrentUser() {
        return (User) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
    }

    // Сменить пароль !!!!!!!!!!!!!!! РАЗОБРАТЬСЯ ЧТО ТАК А ЧТО НЕТ
    public void changePassword(String login, String newPass) {
        /**НПЕ из того что не находит юзера с таким логином**/
        User user = userRepository.getByLogin(login);

        try {
            user.setPassword(newPass);
            userRepository.save(user);
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            throw new NullPointerException("Ошибка! Указанный Вами логин не существует!"); // Надо посмотреть в чем дело
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        } catch (NotFoundException e) {
            throw new NotFoundException(user.getId());
        }
    }


    // Загрузка пользователя по login (метод от интерфейса)
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String login) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = getUserDataByLogin(login);
        if (user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("не нашли" + login);
        }
        return user;
    }


    private User getUserDataByLogin(String login) {
        User user = userRepository.getByLogin(login);
        return user;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Just checking, are you sure that in the `getAuthorities()` method, you are putting in the correct value in role?

Comment: I added a debug screen. I can’t deal with this for 4 days already. 
All code above. I do not understand what you're talking about? I clearly explained the problem above and added code with screenshots

Comment: Try adding ```http.cors().disable().csrf().disable()``` in your ```configure(HttpSecurity http)``` method in the ```WebSecurityConfig```. If you get the problem when calling the api form the browser, this might be the problem.

Comment: You need to add a bit more information and code on HOW you are triggering this error. Are you calling a REST controller? POST? An integraiton test?

Comment: @theshadog GOOD MAN!!!

Comment: Cool, I added an answer, please accept and assign the bounty :)

Comment: @theshadog bounty will be accepted in one hour! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When calling your API from the browser, this error can occur due to CORS/CSRF issues. You can disable both in your `WebSecurityConfig` inside the `configure(HttpSecurity http)` method:

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(jsr250Enabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    // Methods
    //
    // Тут мы переопределяем метод конфигураций
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .cors().disable()
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            ...
    }
}
```

Please be aware that disabling cors and/or csrf might be a security issue in a prod environment.